# Is the Symplectic Schur algebra a 0-faithful cover of the Brauer algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, schur-functors

The symplectic Schur algebra, $Sp_{2n}$ and the Brauer algebra, $B_r(n)$, are in Schur-Weyl duality over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ (this is due to Doty et. al.).  The resulting Schur and inverse-Schur functors take the cell-modules, $S(\lambda)$, for the Brauer algebra to the cell-modules, $\Delta(\lambda)$, for the symplectic Schur algebra and vice-versa (see [1]).

Do we have that

$${\rm Hom}_{B_r(n)} (S(\lambda),S(\mu)) \cong{\rm Hom}_{Sp_{2n}} (\Delta(\lambda),\Delta(\mu)?$$

i.e. is the symplectic Schur algebra a $0$-faithful cover of the Brauer algebra?

And if the answer is no in general, is it yes when the Brauer algebra acts faithfully on tensor space?

[1] Donkin, Tange THE BRAUER ALGEBRA AND THE SYMPLECTIC SCHUR ALGEBRA, arxiv/pdf/0806.4500.pdf